# If temperature is average kinetic energy and objects can't move faster than $c$ then surely there is a max temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, speed-of-light

From what I've been taught in physics in school, temperature is average kinetic energy, particles can't move quicker than the speed of light and there is no max temperature (please correct me if I'm wrong). Surely that is a contradiction.

Comment: Particles approach $E \to \infty$ as $v \to c$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any upper limit on a particles kinetic energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183132/)

Comment: Or [Upper limit to the temperature of a body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/402423/)?

Comment: this observation is a key part of the Chandrasekhar limit. $E/p = \beta$ gets saturated and it's bye bye white dwarf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You surely have [Newton's formula for the kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Newtonian_kinetic_energy) in mind:
$$E_\text{kin}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \tag{1}$$
But this formula is only an approximation
valid for speeds $v$ much smaller than the speed of light $c$.
More exactly you need to use the formula for the [relativistic
kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy):
$$E_\text{kin}=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right) \tag{2}$$

For small speeds ($v\ll c$) you can approximate this formula (2)
by the simpler Newtonian formula (1).
But for larger speeds this approximation is not valid anymore.
And especially for $v\to c$ you get $E_\text{kin}\to\infty$.

And because kinetic energy has no upper limit,
also temperature has no upper limit as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense